# CheckColumn selected values from inside a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am trying to access the number of `checkcolumn`'s selected which are the first columns of a grid.

```
xtype: 'grid',
itemId: "gdMain",
store: {
type: 'webapi',
api: {
    read: 'api/Report/Get'
},
autoLoad: true,
},
columns: [
   { header: 'User', dataIndex: 'user'},
   { header: 'Date', dataIndex: 'date'}
   ], selModel: {
         selType: 'checkboxmodel',
         itemId: 'chkUser',
         showHeaderCheckbox: true
 }
```

I tried using ComponentQuery

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gdMain')
```

But I am not finding any properties that will tell me the number of rows checked.

Please tell me how to get the number of `checkcolumn`'s selected inside a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of selections by accessing the selection model:

`theGrid.getSelectionModel().getCount();`